# help needed to install nvidia driver on ubuntu 13.04 64 bit

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 64-bit

im a newbie here, i was trying to install nvidia driver on ubuntu 13.04 64 bit, i have an Asus laptop with nvidia geforce GT645M, im trying to follow the steps on http://paste.ubuntu.com/5601226/

but when i almost reach the final steps, i can't download some of the files, it gives me '404 not found' msg. the files are the bottom part which after 'cd xstuff', line 81 onwards. (sorry i can't post more links here due to my reputation is still low)

now i'm in the have way this, any helps on this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Replace the links you needed with those you find here: https://launchpad.net/~canonical-x/+archive/x-staging